# Dot product for two matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix, dot-product

How do I compute the dot product for

```
movies <- matrix(c(3,1,1,2,1,4,3,1,1,3), ncol = 2, byrow = T)

users <- matrix(c(1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1), ncol = 2, byrow = T)


expected <- matrix(c(3,1,1,3,1,
                     1,2,4,1,3,
                     3,1,1,3,1,
                     4,3,5,4,4), ncol = 5, byrow = T)
```

This example is from
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZspR5PZemcs
at 12:55

Comment: `users %*% t(movies)` gives the result.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is

```
users %*% t(movies)
```

I have been confused by "dot product" I think this is something different from matrix multiplication.